# Shell variable is not being seen/used in Tmux configuration

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, tmux

I'm trying to use a shell variable in Tmux to configure some settings for the venerable [powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline). The line of interest in my `.tmux.config` is:

```
run-shell "powerline-daemon -q"
source-file $POWERLINE_ROOT/powerline/bindings/tmux/powerline.conf
```

I get the following error :

```
/Users/myname/.tmux.conf:47: /powerline/bindings/tmux/powerline.conf: No such file or directory
```

It seems that the value of the environment variable `$POWERLINE_ROOT` is not being seen by Tmux. (I can confirm that `$POWERLINE_ROOT` does have a non-empty value.)

You can see my complete [Tmux configuration](https://github.com/jlconlin/tmuxConfiguration/blob/master/tmux.conf#L46) if needed

Comment: How are you confirming that `POWERLINE_ROOT` is non-empty? I can confirm that I can use environment variables in my `.tmux.conf` file, so it's not set when your conf file is being used.

Comment: To ensure that the variable is non-empty I can do `echo $POWERLINE_ROOT`. However, that only tells me that it is set in bash. I really don't know how to ensure its value in Tmux. I would hope that there is an "echo" function that can be done in the configuration, but I don't know what that is.

Comment: You appear to know about `run-shell`. You could use that to echo to a file to show that it isn't set. As for setting the variable, I believe setting it in the shell that you call tmux from should work (setting it, then starting a tmux session); I don't think setting it inside a tmux window/pane will do what you want.

Comment: @jeremysprofile You assume too much of my expertise. I only know about `run-shell` because I copied it from someone else. That being said, I did use it to write the variable to a file as you suggested. The variable was not set. However, it is set in the shell before I start Tmux so I'm not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's all I know:

I have the following in my `.bashrc`:

```sh
export __tmux_bg_inactive='234'
export __tmux_bg_active='233'
export __tmux_fg_inactive='245'
export __tmux_fg_active='248'
```

I have the following in my `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g window-style "fg=colour${__tmux_fg_inactive},bg=colour${__tmux_bg_inactive}" 
set -g window-active-style "fg=colour${__tmux_fg_active},bg=colour${__tmux_bg_active}" 
set -g pane-active-border-style "fg=colour$__green, bg=colour$__tmux_bg_active"
set -g pane-border-style "fg=colour$__tmux_fg_inactive, bg=colour$__tmux_bg_inactive"
```

This works for me. Maybe the fact that I've `export`'d the variable is what did it, or maybe it's that it's in my `.bashrc` so it gets set everywhere `tmux` could possibly need it?

Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: I've done the same thing; that is, I export the variables in my `.bashrc` and then I try to use them in `.tmux.conf`. After Tmux starts (with the error), I can `echo $POWERLINE_ROOT` in the shell and I see that it has an appropriate value. I can also do `:source-file $POWERLINE_ROOT/powerline/bindings/tmux/powerline.conf` in Tmux after it starts and still get the same error.

Comment: BTW, I like your name (same as mine!)

Comment: you exported the variables in your bashrc, then sourced your bashrc, then started tmux?

Comment: I thought I had exported, but now that I double check my configuration I forgot the little `export` word. `<feeling_sheepish>`Sorry for making you do all this when I'm just being dense.`</feeling_sheepish>`